# Why is each rep off by 1 when sorting Users by year vs. all on a < 1-year-old SE site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, sorting, users-page

Best place to see this is on a new beta site, which is where I noticed it, so...

1. Go to PETS.stackexchange.com
2. Navigate to the [Users page and sort by ALL](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all).  Note any or all users.
3. Now [sort by YEAR](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year).

Notice how everyone has a 1 point of reputation difference between the two sorts?

Seems like an odd bug to me.  I searched on meta and found a few about reputation discrepancies, but nothing specific to the users page.

Comment: I don't think its a bug seems like its just removing the 1 rep giving automatically when an account is created and btw How is pets? :)

Comment: You start with 1 rep. This doesn't count in the rep you _acquired_ during the year.

Comment: @Tijesunimi - It's doing OK.  Not too many new questions, but we had an odd user influx at the start of last week.

Comment: @Oded - that makes sense.  Now I get what Tijesunimi meant.  Status-bydesign this beast then; thanks.

Comment: It's the same reason why people can have 'negative rep' if a timespan is chosen that is shorter than the lifetime of the project. To be honest, it isn't too clear that the rep shown for the normal view is total rep, while for other timespans it is a delta.

Comment: @JoshDM - "beast" is a bit much. Given the subject matter (and example site), wouldn't "puppy" be more appropriate?

Comment: @Oded Could you post your answer as an answer so this question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everyone starts with 1 rep, which is not something your acquired or earned - just the minimum reputation possible.

The ALL sort get *all* reputation, including this 1 rep.

The YEAR sort will account for any rep earned in that year.

For anyone who has been around less than a year, that's the discrepancy.

And of course, for any site that has been around less than a year, **everyone** will have this 1 rep discrepancy between the pages.

Comment: That's great, but it isn't obvious to us users that there is a difference between the different "tabs" other than the time frame (which we click on and expect it to be displaying the same data for each time period).