# Why does the user reputation change for a 3 day old site?

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, reputation, private-beta, users-page

On reputation `filter=all`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and with `filter=year`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

This is a 3 day old private beta ([elementary OS](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82707/elementary-os)). Why is it changing the reputation of people (and therefore the order)?

Note that other tabs (e.g. month) are also off.

Comment: What site? Anyone can access it via the Area 51 proposal, so please post a link so we can reproduce.

Comment: I see different numbers under each person (eg Rafael 615 in one, 499 in the other) so the issue seems to be that more than the order. They are in number order in both shots

Comment: @KateGregory edited

Comment: for the people whose rep differs by 1, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209667/why-is-each-rep-off-by-1-when-sorting-users-by-year-vs-all-on-a-1-year-old-se?rq=1

Comment: Okay, that explains some, but Rafael has a big difference.

Comment: Weird, looks like the calculation for "year" went off and was cached this way.

Answer (score 8):

As Kate Gregory already pointed out in the comments, a difference of 1 is already explained in [Why is each rep off by 1 when sorting Users by year vs. all on a < 1-year-old SE site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209667/why-is-each-rep-off-by-1-when-sorting-users-by-year-vs-all-on-a-1-year-old-se).

There are two other issues you've uncovered here, though:

1. When you get the association bonus (+100 because you have 200+ rep on any SE site), these +100 are *not* counted towards the daily/weekly/monthly/yearly totals. However when a user's reputation is recalculated, the +100 *are* included in those tallies. Therefore, if a user has the association bonus, the difference between their yearly value and their total is

   - 1, if the user's reputation has been recalculated after they've received the bonus (which, for example, happens automatically when they had reputation changes based on posts that were later deleted), and
   - 101, if the reputation has not been recalculated.

   A point could be made for either of these approaches (including the bonus or not), but of course it should be consistent.
2. There's a bug which causes the reputation event that pushes you over 200 to not be recorded in the daily/weekly/etc. tallies. That is, if you get +10 because somebody upvotes your answer, after which you have 205 rep (but don't have 200+ on any other site), then you gain a total of +110, but your daily/weekly/etc. values do not change, not even by the +10 which should happen regardless of what the expected behavior in point 1. is. (This discrepany would be fixed by a recalculation).

This answer is just a heads-up for you; neither of these two is fixed yet; I want to talk to Nick first what the best approach is to handle and repair these issues.

Comment: Any update or is this bottom of the todo list? :P